# JSON get Javascript from API, but I want to get from my own work

Tags: javascript, json

So currently I have a code that get's random quotes from https://forismatic.com/en/api/ , using this code in my **main.js** file:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false,
  "error": function() {
    init()
  }
});

function init () {
  $.getJSON('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=0&format=json&lang=en').then(function (data) {
    $('blockquote').html(data.quoteText)
  });
}
```

How can I change this so I can create my own sheet with quotes and display it on the same way?

Comment: Do you want to setup your own server at a place to fetch the quotes or do you simply want to read some JSON (e.g. from a file)?

Comment: @BreakBB Just read from a simple file.

Comment: Have you tried to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)? Or just use an array with quotes and set those in `.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a flat file (or you can, but not with this method) with quotes on it, you need to create an API, which will require a server. You can use node.js for this if you are comfortable with javascript, but you can use any language really.

There are many simple guides online on how to do this, for Node.js they will generally use Express for the server, and some may suggest using a database such as MongoDB (I would suggest avoiding that for such a simple task at this point).

Comment: I tried to do something like this: https://pastebin.com/Th0tNfB3 (look at the 2 functions I added), but it doesn't display any quotes.